# OnEditorActionListener not working when testing

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm using OnEditorActionListener on a EditText

```
scoreboardNameEdit.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Everything worked well during development and when testing manually. Now i want to test it with Android Espresso

```
onView(withId(tv_id)).perform(typeText(to_type)).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
```

and the OnEditorActionListener does not get called

Is this a common problem with Android Espresso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closeSoftKeyboard()`: sounds to me like that is only hiding the keyboard.
Try to use one of the different methods in [ViewActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions).

From the docs:

- `ViewActions#closeSoftKeyboard()` : Returns an action that closes soft keyboard.
- `ViewActions#pressImeActionButton()` : Returns an action that presses the current action button (next, done, search, etc) on the IME (Input Method Editor).

I would place my bet on `pressImeActionButton()` (untested offcourse)